# I/O files matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io

I would link to do some commands to:

- access to folder which isn't in my current working folder
- list the content of folder
- access to a file and read it to search a specific string

Comment: What have you tried so far ?  How much experience do you have with Matlab ?

Comment: I begin with matlab and I try to do this example

Comment: Have you read any of the, generally very good, documentation that the Mathworks publish on their website ?  I think that familiarising yourself with the User's Guide should be your first step.

Comment: thanks for your suggession , but I  don't find what I'm looking for in documentation, there are a lot of commands and uses cases and it is not really obvious to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an image file in jpeg format in another folder named `myimage` and a text file called `mytext`, use:

```
prefix_image='myimage';
prefix_data='mytext';
fileformat='.jpg';
dataformat='.txt';
folder='C:\Users\khaled\Documents\MATLAB';

image = imread(strcat(folder,prefix_image,fileformat));

data=textread(strcat(folder,prefix_data,fileformat),'%f');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many built-in functions:

- `dir` to list files in directory: http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/dir.html
- `fopen` to open a file by its filename: http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/fopen.html
- `fread` to continually (by using a while loop with `feof`) read a file: http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/fread.html
- `strfind` to find a string in another: http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/strfind.html

Try it :)

Comment: I would like to find a string in a file

Answer (score 0):

- You can open a dialog to get a path with [uigetdir](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/uigetdir.html)
- List the folder content with [dir](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/dir.html)
- Open the file with [fopen](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/fopen.html)
- Use e.g. [fileread](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/fileread.html) to read the content of the file
- And don't forget to close the file afterwards with [fclose](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/fclose.html)

Comment: please, how I access to a folder which isn't in my current dir whithout making cd... and nor the full path to folder ?

Comment: @lola: You can also use relative pathnames. e.g. `output = fileread('../some_other_folder/my_file.txt');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative filepaths ('..' means 'parent directory') to locate the file you need. As others have said, you can use fopen and fread to open the file. These are low-level file i/o functions that Matlab has ported from C. If your input file is formatted consistently (ascii, a fixed number of columns of values, etc.) then you can look into higher-level functions like importdata. For example, to import a CSV file into a matrix, you could use:

```
myMatrix = importData('../../myFile.csv', ',', 3);
```

where the comma is the delimeter, and there are 3 headerlines before the data columns start. You do not need to use fopen or format specifiers when you use importdata, which makes life a lot easier.